# Dual Y-Axis and subplot using Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to generate a plot that has rainfall data plotted at the top and water level data at two locations plotted below (with a dual Y-Axis as the ranges of the two locations are significantly different.

I have successfully generated these two plots individually, but when using `subplot`, the second water level time series plots on the upper graph, and all axes labels are missing.

I'd appreciate help with 
1. Plotting the second water level time series on the correct part of the subplot.
2. Plotting the axis labels correctly

```
#Set up left X axis
ay <- list(
  title = "Stream Level (cm)",
  zeroline = TRUE,
  showgrid = FALSE,
  range=c(0,30)
)

#Set up right Y axis
by <- list(
  tickfont = list(color = "red"),
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right",
  title = "Bund Level (cm)",
  tick = 0,
  zeroline = TRUE,
  showgrid = FALSE,
  range=c(0,80)
)

#Plot water levels
p_30 <- ms_merged_30 %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_lines(x = ~date, y = ~MS1_cm, name = "Stream_1 Level") %>%
  add_lines(x = ~date, y = ~MS2_cm, name = "Stream_2 Level", yaxis = "y2") %>%
  layout(
    title = "", yaxis = ay,  yaxis2 = by,
    xaxis = list(title="x")
  )

#Plot rainfall
rain_plot <- rain_data %>%
  plot_ly(type = "bar") %>%
  add_bars(x = ~DateTime, y = ~Rainfall, name = "Rainfall")

#Make subplot to combine hydrograph and hyteograph
combined_plot <- subplot(rain_plot, p_30, nrows = 2, heights = c(0.3,0.7), shareX = TRUE)
```

Individual water level plot
[image: Individual water level plot]
Individual rainfall plot
[image: Individual rainfall plot]
Combined plot, plotting incorrectly
[image: Combined plot, plotting incorrectly]